# How to display the name and etc with in a column; pandas

Tags: pandas

```
print(data_df['gross'].nlargest(3))
```

So I want to display the top 3 value in a columns with a csv file, and thats my code that works. But how can I also display it with the name, gross, genre, etc?

[Heres an image of what im saying.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kD5TR.png)

I want the top 3 value and the name, gross,etc

output like this:

Rank 1: Hackers, $7564000, PG-13, Comedy|Crime|Drama|Thriller

Answer (score 0):

You can use, it means show top 3 rows sorted by column 'gross'

data_df.nlargest(3, 'gross')

To display only 3 columns mentioned

```
data_df[['gross', 'genres', 'language']].nlargest(3, 'gross')
```

Comment: How about just specific ones? Like gross, genre, & language?

Comment: Do you mean, you want to display the three columns but largest by gross?

Comment: Yes, thats what I mean. Sorry for confusion

Comment: Is there a way to make it neater? here's the output: https://snag.gy/z1EQ3d.jpg

Making it neat like this: 

Rank 1: Hackers, $7564000, PG-13, Comedy|Crime|Drama|Thriller

Comment: data_df[['gross', 'genres', 'language']] is the best way to select only a few columns from a larger dataframe as far as I am aware